Reconstruct Kernel from sampling a Gaussian Process
I am generating 50K draws from Gaussian Process with GPy in python. The Gaussian Process has a RBF kernel with length scale = 10. I want to check that the estimate of the covariance matrix from this sample of 50K draws matches the form of the RBF kernel. I am computing the estimate of the covariance matrix with the numpy function np.cov.
Problem: The RBF kernel has maximum 1, when $r_{ij} = (x_i - x_j)^2 = 0$. The maximum of the estimate of the covariance matrix is not 1, but a value close to 0.175. Why? Am I missing some rescaling?
Generation of the Gaussian Process's sample
import GPy

T = 200 # Number of time points
n_samples = 50000 # Number of samples

# Define the input range
X = np.linspace(0, T, T).reshape(-1, 1)

# Define a zero mean function
mean_function = GPy.mappings.Constant(input_dim=1, output_dim=1, value=0)

# Define a RBF kernel
kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1., lengthscale=10.)

# Create a Gaussian Process model
gp = GPy.models.GPRegression(X, np.zeros((T, 1)), kernel)

# Generate samples from the Gaussian Process
samples = gp.posterior_samples_f(X, full_cov=True, size=n_samples).reshape(T,-1)

Visualization of the theoretical kernel
import numpy as np
def RBF_kernel(x1, x2, l):
    return np.exp(-0.5 * (x1 - x2) ** 2 / l ** 2)

x = np.linspace(0, 200, 200)
X, XP = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z = RBF_kernel(X, XP,10)
ax = sns.heatmap(Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.invert_yaxis()


Estimating the covariance matrix from the sample
mean_function = np.mean(samples, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

fullsample_demeanized = samples - mean_function
cov_matrix = np.cov(fullsample_demeanized)

ax = sns.heatmap(cov_matrix, cmap='viridis', square=True)
ax.invert_yaxis()


